# Why a dictionary is not modified after passing it through a function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have read that the list and the dictionaries are mutable objects i.e it will change its values globally if it is modified inside a function. 
As an experiment, I passed a dictionary containing values as dictionary type to a function that adds a few more keys to the value items, but the function returns the same dictionary without adding the extra keys. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
def add_invert_nhbrs(knng):
    invert_n = {key: {} for key in knng.keys()}    
    top_k = 3#len(knng[0].keys())
    for index in knng.keys():
        for inv in knng[index].keys():
            invert_n[inv][index] = knng[index][inv]        
    for index in knng.keys():
        invert_n[index] = dict((x,y) for x,y in sorted(invert_n[index].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:4*top_k])
        knng[index] = {**knng[index], **invert_n[index]}

    return knng

knng, r = k_nhbrs(10)
sim_list = add_invert_nhbrs(knng)
```

knng structure: {0: {2:32, 3:43, 5:32}, 1:{2:22, 3:11, 9:98}, 2:{},...}

I get the desired result if the updated value items are stored in a new empty dictionary.

```
def add_invert_nhbrs(knng):
    invert_n = {key: {} for key in knng.keys()}    
    top_k = len(knng[0].keys())
    graph = {}
    for index in knng.keys():
        for inv in knng[index].keys():
            invert_n[inv][index] = knng[index][inv]        
    for index in knng.keys():
        invert_n[index] = dict((x,y) for x,y in sorted(invert_n[index].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:4*top_k])
        graph[index] = {**knng[index], **invert_n[index]}

    return graph
```

Can anyone explain why is it so?

Comment: In line 3 you have `top_k = len(knng[0].keys())` but I do not see key `0` in your `knng` dictionary.

Comment: Actually, the dictionary is of fixed length for each key. In the post, I just showed how the knng looks like, but also it contains the key:0 as well.

Comment: I called `add_invert_nbrs` with `{0: {0: 32, 1: 22}, 1: {0: 43, 1: 3}}` and it returned `{0: {0: 32, 1: 43}, 1: {0: 22, 1: 3}}`. This is not `the same dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

What does your global code look like? You're passing knng and then returning it, but what do you do with the returned value?

```
mydict = {'a':'dict'}

def changeDict(mydict):
  # change mydict
  return mydict
```

When you call your function, you want to store the returned value:

```
mydict = changeDict(mydict)
```